# External Oscillator charging RST Cap when chip is not powered on

Tags: oscillator

I have a chip (Hub USB) with an external oscillator. Chip is powered with 5V and external oscillator is powered with 12V.

When I have power on the oscillator but not on the chip, the Reset pin charges a bit (through XI - internal circuitry) and if I power the 5V after that, the chip fails to initialize properly. It works if I only enable the 12V after the 5V.

My question is, there are a passive way (without a mcu, ampop or smith trigger) to drive the Reset Pin to Low if I only have the 12V On?

Edit: Somehow the board worked on the client assembly with current configuration. But already implementing a voltage supervisor circuit to make sure RESET pin is low if chip VDD is not stable for next version.

Comment: You should include a circuit and links to the actual oscillator and chip you're using. As as this question is too vague and leaves too much space for wild guesses.

Comment: This is a pretty common situation when an external clock charges up voltage rail on an entire unpowered IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is really the reset pin, the chip is powered by the clock signal through the protection diode on OSC IN. Put some load on the VDD and a resistor in the OSC path and this should lower the VDD enough to reset the chip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSitF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or simply use a three terminal reset chip like [this](http://www.ti.com/power-management/supervisor-reset-ic/products.html#p790typ=4.38&p2059=Active-low)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A voltage supervisor circuit is the solution. Already made a working implementation using the TLC7725. But maybe will change to a cheaper one.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I assume you have negative reset logic, where LOW level means "reset". In that case, tie the reset pin to 5V via a resistor. This will sink any residual voltage the pin may pick through the oscillator circuit while the 5V voltage is off. When the 5V voltage appears, it will drive your reset pin HIGH, enabling the chip to start.

Comment: "In that case, tie the reset pin to 5V via a resistor"
I think you mean tie to GND with a resistor, right?

Will try that.

Comment: No, this won't work, because the entire power rail will be charged up by clock signal via ESD clamps. Pulling down RST (driven by most simplistic RC) won't work either. The OP needs to use an active voltage monitor IC to prevent this charge up.

Comment: Ali Chen you are right. I measure power on the RST pin but other things may be happening on the chip that shouldn't and could mess up. Maybe will just implement a Voltage Supervisor circuit to make sure to keep the Reset pin on low before have a stable 5V power rail. On in the last case, cut the 12V power rail if 5V is not present.